# Having Run-time-error 1004 Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I have a simple formula in vba, like this :

```
 Sub button_fu()

Windows("H1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("jan").Activate
Range("J3").Select

Range("J3").Formula = "=IF((VLOOKUP(C3,'[FOLLOW UP H1.xlsx]jan'!$C$8:$M$100,8,False))=1,""terhubung"",IF((VLOOKUP(C3,'[FOLLOW UP H1.xlsx]jan'!$C$8:$M$100,9,False))=1,""unreach"",IF((VLOOKUP(C3,'[FOLLOW UP H1.xlsx]jan'!$C$8:$M$100,10,False))=1,""reject"",IF((VLOOKUP(C3,'[FOLLOW UP H1.xlsx]jan'!$C$8:$M$100,11,False))=1,""workload"","""")"

End Sub
```

anyone hepl me, how the problem solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some closing brackets in your formula:

```
Sub button_fu()

    Windows("H1.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("jan").Activate
    Range("J3").Select

    Range("J3").Formula = "=IF((VLOOKUP(C3,'[FOLLOW UP H1.xlsx]jan'!$C$8:$M$100,8,False))=1,""terhubung"",IF((VLOOKUP(C3,'[FOLLOW UP H1.xlsx]jan'!$C$8:$M$100,9,False))=1,""unreach"",IF((VLOOKUP(C3,'[FOLLOW UP H1.xlsx]jan'!$C$8:$M$100,10,False))=1,""reject"",IF((VLOOKUP(C3,'[FOLLOW UP H1.xlsx]jan'!$C$8:$M$100,11,False))=1,""workload"",""""))))"

End Sub
```

P.S. Should "FOLLOW UP H1.xlsx" be "H1.xlsm", or do you have another workbook?